# google actions: using new line character in BasicCard when reading from Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, actions-on-google

This is on using a new line (two spaces followed by \n) required in the BasicCard when reading the text string from Firestore.

Assume I have stored a string as: `The options are:  \n1. One.  \n2.Two` as a string in a FireStore document. When I read and populate it to a BasicCard text, the simulator response shows that the single backslash has been replaced by a double backslash, viz. `The options are:  \\n1. One.  \\n2.Two`.

I tried running the Javascript replace command: `str.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');` still the result shows two backslashes in the simulator response.

I tried running the Javascript replace command: `str.replace(/\\n/g, '\\n');` still the result shows two backslashes in the simulator response.

I tried running the Javascript replace command: `str.replace(/\\\\n/g, '\\n');` still the result shows two backslashes in the simulator response.

When I log the converted string it shows correct, yet puts a double backslash in the response. I tried all of the above options yet the formatted text in the json always shows two backslashes. The problem seems to be something in the way Firestore stores escape characters because if I hard code a string with `[space][space]\n` there is a new line in the BasicCard screen.

Thanks

Comment: To be clear, what is stored in Firestore is a litteral <space><space><backslash><n>? four characters? (rather than <space><space><newline> three characters?)

Comment: @Prisoner. Just to clarify. If I store for example, `...end.  \nA...` (showing the end of a sentence and the beginning of a new one with two spaces and a slash n) as a string field, then in the google-actions json, it appears as `..end.  \\nA..` i.e. it puts a second slash before `'n`

Comment: How are you storing that in firestore?

Comment: (ie - typing it in via the editor. using a program to put it in. etc)

Comment: pasting it in via console.firestore ... ... since I am testing. Once done I will write an upload code, I guess

Comment: funnily other utf8 codes like `&bull;` (for bullets) etc work

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on [Basic Card](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card) states:

> Note the two spaces before '\n' required 
>   for a line break to be
>   rendered in the card.

So, I'm on mobile so I may not be seeing your code correctly, but do you add two spaces in your JS replace statements?

I'm not sure about the firebase side of the issue but as far as AoG goes, that might be the problem.

Comment: Yes, I did add two spaces @Yuksel Tolun. In fact, have tried all combinations in my JS replace code. Currently, just avoiding the line break.

Comment: Another work around would be to save data in the firestore by splitting it from the line break points. For example: instead of having `data: 'line1  \nline2` you might save it as: `data1: line1` and `data2: line2`. Then you can add the line break in your fulfillment.

Comment: In my use-case it probably will not make sense. I am try to let folks search for content on topic name and it will read/ display out the content. Hence some content may be split over multiple lines and some may be just one or two lines. A good idea tho. Thanks @Yuksel

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the bug once I'm at home but in the mean time firestore community has some similar questions. Maybe one of them might be the correct way to go.